# jquery slider (or infinite cycle) plugin that changes class instead of style attribute

Tags: jquery, css, slider, css-transitions

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin that is either a slider or similar (cycles through a list of elements infinitely), but that changes the class attributes, not the style attributes?

I know I could probably write such a script pretty easily, but I'm hoping there's one out there that already has all the usual bells and whistles (next/prev buttons option, pager option, timeout setting, etc.). With all that, it'll take me a long time to learn how to write this and I figure I'm probably not the first person who has thought of it.

All the jQuery sliders and carousels I've found in my search manipulate style attributes, which gives me no CSS control over transitions. If they added/removed classes like "active," "next," "prev," "transitionStarted", "transitionEnded", etc. I could do a lot with the transitions using CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [jquerytools](http://jquerytools.org/) ? The scrollable feature has custom and default classes, and you can always change the css to suit your needs.

Comment: No. Thanks for introducing me to it! It's a pretty impressive set of tools for being such a vast library. Seems like they keep it pretty simple too (minimal javascript activity to produce the results), which is really good. However, it still uses the style attribute for all of the transitions, and doesn't use the class attribute. So this wouldn't suit my needs.